# DiscordBot:Unable to resolve service for type 'Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient' while attempting to activate 'LockDocler.Services.CommandHandler

Tags: c#, discord.net

Im trying to make bot for discord on Discord.net for first time.

Here's my code.

```
   class StartUp
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public StartUp(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddYamlFile("_config.yml");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public static async Task RunAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var startup = new StartUp(args);
        await startup.RunAsync(); 
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        provider.GetRequiredService<CommandHandler>();

        await provider.GetRequiredService<StartUpService>().StartAsync();
        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }
    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(new DiscordShardedClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose,
            MessageCacheSize = 1000

        }))
        .AddSingleton(new CommandService(new CommandServiceConfig
        {
            LogLevel = Discord.LogSeverity.Verbose,
            DefaultRunMode = RunMode.Async,
            CaseSensitiveCommands = false
        }))
        .AddSingleton<CommandHandler>()
        .AddSingleton<StartUpService>()
        .AddSingleton(Configuration);
    }
}
```

}

problem on string   `provider.GetRequiredService<CommandHandler>();`

Code of CommandHandler

```
class CommandHandler
{
    public static IServiceProvider _provider;
    public static DiscordSocketClient _discord;
    public static CommandService commands;
    public static IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient discord, CommandService command, IConfigurationRoot conf, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _config = conf;
        _discord = discord;
        commands = command;


        _discord.Ready += OnReady;
    }

    private Task OnReady()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"been connected as user {_discord.CurrentUser.Username}#{_discord.CurrentUser.Discriminator}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Exeption: "Unable to resolve service for type 'Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient' while attempting to activate 'LockDocler.Services.CommandHandler".
I have no idea to solve this, thanks right away.

Answer (score 1):

In `CommandHandler` you inject a `DiscordSocketClient`, but in `ConfigureServices` you're registering a `DiscordShardedClient`.

You either need to:

1. Register a `DiscordSocketClient`, or
2. Inject a `DiscordShardedClient`.

If you're unsure which to use there's some documentation [here](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/dev/docs/faq/basics/client-basics.md#what-is-a-shardsharded-client-and-how-is-it-different-from-the-discordsocketclient)